Brython's 'set_loop_timeout' not working within asynchronous code—any solutions?
While developing my code, I encountered an issue where the webpage becomes unresponsive and irrecoverable when an infinite loop is executed in async mode. While searching for a solution, I found a related discussion here. I tried applying the suggestions to my code, but it didn't work as expected.
Here's my code:
from browser import document, window, aio, console, timer

# Set loop timeout
timer.set_loop_timeout(10)

...

def processInput(event=None):
    global input_values
    # Clear previous output
    document["mainConsole"].innerHTML = ""
    # Execute the script
    aio.run(exec_script())

async def exec_script():
    try:
        ${solutiontext}  # This may include an infinite loop
    except BrythonNotRunningError:
        on_compile_done()
        return
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
    finally:
        on_compile_done()

processInput()

The problem is that when the solutiontext variable contains an infinite loop like while(1):, the entire webpage freezes. It seems that the set_loop_timeout(10) option doesn't work within the asynchronous function exec_script().
Has anyone encountered this issue before? How can I prevent or handle infinite loops in asynchronous Brython code?

not sure why the javascript tag

Browser scripts are single-threaded, you shouldn't have infinite loops. There's no difference between a Brython while True: loop and a JavaScript while(true) loop.

@Barmar But I can't know what code will be excuted with brython. The code that is executed is entered by the user, and is difficult to control. Is there only one way through hard coding?

That's a general problem with executing user-supplied code. Why would it be any different with Brython than JavaScript?
